# how to convert 2 hex bytes to milliseconds

Tags: php

I am just having issue to convert this byte **2c 00** to milliseconds using PHP. This is what I was doing but it just prints 0000

```
$timestamp = hexdec(implode(array_reverse(explode(' ', '2c 00'))));
var_dump($timestamp);
$result = sprintf('%d%03d', $timestamp[1], $timestamp[0] * 1000);
echo $result;
```

Comment: $timestamp is a number, why are you trying to access offsets?

Comment: when I try i get `0d`

Comment: 2a 8e dc 21    - Last updated time in Seconds (Seconds that have elapsed since January 1Midnight, 2000) - 4 Byte
For convert to standard epoch time, add time offset value 946684800 (Time offset from Jan 1970 to Jan 2000)
                                                                                                                       
 2c 00            - Last updated time Millisecond portion - 2 Byte
...This is actually what i had to do..it has to parts fort 2 convert 4bytes and than 2 bytes to milliseconds

Comment: now only 2 bytes conversion to milliseconds remains

Comment: So what output are you expecting from this?

Comment: @MuhammadBilal . 2c 00 is actually two bytes.  Is the value your trying to convert 0x2c00 to 11264 decimal.  Which would represent 11,264 ms.  I'm a little confused on what the input and output your trying to manipulate and create.

Comment: This is am getting after converting 4bytes of 2a 8e dc 21 -> Fri, 22 Dec 2017 08:51:34 .............. now i had to convert 2c 00 to milliseconds something like 689793 or something like this.

Comment: *************this is the code i used that converted 4 hex bytes ***********                              $timestamp = hexdec(implode(array_reverse(explode(' ', '2a ba ce 21'))))
echo "seconds:  ", $timestamp+946684800, "\n";//else
echo "readable: ", date('r', $timestamp+946684800), "\n";

Comment: now i can't use this way to convert 2c 00 hex to milliseconds if there is some other way kindly do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first step you're turning this back into a decimal number (with `implode()` and then `hexdec()`) but then in the next step you try treating it like an array. That isn't going to work. Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
$timestamp = explode(' ', '2c 00');
$result    = sprintf('%d%03d', hexdec($timestamp[0]), hexdec($timestamp[1]) * 1000);
echo $result;
```

Comment: i have asked for real time data instead of just hex to confirm it...but for now i think this is it